# Writing an XPath query to match elements based on attributes and content

Tags: xslt, string, xpath, expression

I have some XML like this:

```
<topics>
  <topic id="50"/>
  <topic id="51"/>
  <topic id="52"/>
</topics>

<discussions>
  <discussion type="foo">talked about T50 as Discussion 1000</discussion>
  <discussion type="bar">Food is yummy!</discussion>
  <discussion type="foo">talked about T52 as Discussion 1050</discussion>
</discussions>
```

Given a particular topic ID (`$topicID`), I would like to do the following:

- Devise an XPath expression which is true if there is a `<discussion>` with `type="foo"` that contains the text `T$topicID as Discussion <corresponding-discussion-id>`.
- Devise an XPath expression which, given that `$topicID`, will extract the text `Discussion <corresponding-discussion-id>`.

Is this possible?

---

#### Update:

For the first one, I'm thinking I need something like:

```
exists(
 //discussions/discussion[
  @type="foo" and
  contains(text(), concat($topicId, ??? ))  <-- What goes here? I think we need
 ]                                           some kind of matches(...) around the
)                                            concat(), too.
```

Comment: What environment (XSLT, C#, etc) are you calling this xpath from?

Comment: XSLT. It's inside of Altova StyleVision 2010.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following XPath will select the discussions attribute type="foo" and containing the text "T50 as Discussion" (when $topicid=50).

```
//discussions/discusson[@type='foo' and contains(., concat('T', $topicid, ' as Discussion ')]
```

Given a particular discussion element, the corresponding id is given by:

```
substring-after(normalize-space(.),' as Discussion ')
```

We can combine the 2 by replacing "." in the second expression with the entire first expression. Note that if multiple discussions match the inner expression, we will concat their values from the second.

```
substring-after(normalize-space(
    //discussions/discusson[@type='foo' and contains(., concat('T', $topicid, ' as Discussion ')]
),' as Discussion ')
```

If there were multiple matching discussions, you might process them like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//topics/topic">
    <xsl:variable name="topicid" select="@id" />
    <xsl:for-each select="//discussions/discusson[@type='foo' and contains(., concat('T', $topicid, ' as Discussion ')]">
        <xsl:variable name="relatedid" select="substring-after(normalize-space(.),' as Discussion ')" />

        <!-- do something with $topicid and $relatedid -->

    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Function references:

- [concat()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-concat)
- [contains()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-contains)
- [substring-after()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-substring-after)

Personally, I cannot imagine doing serious XSLT development without Michael Kay's book nearby.

Comment: Would retrieving the second one be something like `//discussions/discussion[...]/substring-after(...)`?

Comment: This worked splendidly! Thanks very much for a thorough and complete answer, Lachlan. I wish I had more upvotes to give.

Comment: This is eerily similar to some work I just did today! Are you guys spying on me? ;)

Answer (score 1):

Does a discussion of `type=foo` contains corresponding `topicID`:

```
/discussions/discussion[@type=foo AND contains(.,'T52')]
```